# hide/show menu item based on logon credential

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project (C# windows application) I have one login page, mdiparent(Consist menustrips) form and 5-6 childforms.
What I want, is that when user fills the login credential, the parent form will be displayed with some menu items been disabled or hidden according to its credential.

To do show, I, had created an parametrized constructor of parent form and passed the username and usertype in it.

LoginPage Code:

```
   smsparent sp = new smsparent(usertype, username);
   sp.Show();
   this.Hide();
```

Parentform code:

```
   public smsparent(string usertype, string username)
   {
         InitializeComponent();

         this.usertype= usertype;
         this.username = username;                

         if (string.Compare(usertype,"Accountant") == 0)
         {
           administratorToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
         }     

    }
```

The problem is that the if block is not been executing.  I have tried .CompareTo(), Equals() and none of them are working.

Comment: you are disabling the administratorToolStripMenuItem, not show/hide as you say in question title.
with the if problem, what is usertype value at runtime? are you sure it is "Accountant" in your case? (debug it!) (btw, for comparing strings you can use == , but string.Compare is ok as well)

Comment: the value at runtime is "Accountant" and to confirm it. I checked it by passing usertype in messagebox before if block.

Comment: be careful, MessageBox is not the best tool to spot subtle differences: a space at the end of a string, or something similar. try also to check usertype.Length vs "Accountant".Lengh, or usertype.ToLower() == "Accountant".ToLower()); // is your case the same in the 2 strings?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare your strings, try

```
if(usertype == "Accountant")
{
    administratorToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
}
```

EDIT

If you want a little more reliability to your comparing, you can do this

```
if(usertype.Trim().ToLower() == "accountant")
{
    administratorToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
}
```

This will remove any whitespaces before or after in `usertype` and also for all letters to lowercase, then compare to `"accountant"`

Comment: Thanks buddy, it helped the problem was a blank left in usertype

Comment: `ToLowerInvariant()` would be better if you don't want surprises for example with Turkish locale (there I and i are different letters)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Neat, I've personally never had to worry about it being culture-insensitive, but I might start using `ToLowerInvariant()` for good practices.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (String.Equals(usertype,"Accountant"))
```

ensures you to go well in this method (Log)

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if usertype is not null and then make a equal check.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(usertype) && String.Equals(usertype.ToLower(),"accountant"))
{
   ...
}
```